# Highlighting "Legal Moves" In chess-like game on panel array- Java

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jpanel

this is more of a logic question than syntax but I'm sure you guys have better ways to do it than me anyway. So I have some pieces (JLabels) on a board (11x11 Grid of JPanels on a JPanel) all in a frame. I'm trying to highlight the "possible moves" for these pieces (I.E. how many panels they can cross in a move) very similar to in many online chessgames. I have the logic that checks if movement follows the rules, and it works perfect, I just can't seem to figure out how to find all of those legal moves at once and use them.

This is the code that I use to check if movement is legal:

```
public void movePieces(MouseEvent me)
{
            MouseEvent e = me;        
            if (turnCount%2 == 1 && pieceCheck[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)])
            {
                if (playerOne && (logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 0 || logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 2 || logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 4))
                {
                    otherCount = logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)];
                    tempX = e.getX();
                    tempY = e.getY();
                    paintPossible(tempX, tempY);
                    turnCount++;
                }
                if (!playerOne && (logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 1 || logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 3 || logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == 5))
                {
                    otherCount = logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)];
                    tempX = e.getX();
                    tempY = e.getY();
                    turnCount++;
                }
            }
            else if ((turnCount%2 == 0 && logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] == -1 && !pieceCheck[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)]) && (Math.abs(tempX - e.getX()) <= xInc && (Math.abs(tempY - e.getY()) <= yInc) || ((Math.abs(tempX - e.getX()) <= 2*xInc) && (Math.abs(tempY - e.getY()) < yInc/4)) || ((Math.abs(tempX - e.getX()) < xInc/4) && (Math.abs(tempY - e.getY()) <= 2*yInc))))
            {
                panels[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)].add(pieces[otherCount]);
                logic[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] = otherCount;
                pieceCheck[(e.getY()/yInc)][(e.getX()/xInc)] = true;
                pieceCheck[tempY/yInc][tempX/xInc] = false;
                panels[tempY/yInc][tempX/xInc].setBackground(veryDarkGray);
                panels[tempY/yInc][tempX/xInc].setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
                playerOne = !playerOne;
                turnCount++;
            }
....
}
```

Basically the first if-statement and what's inside is for when you first click a piece, and then if it's your turn then it will set that piece as the next in line to put down, and grab the X-Y coordinates of where it is.
The else-if then activates the next time you click due to the rotation of my turnCount, and makes sure there's no piece where you're clicking and that the space is within a certain# of pixels to where your piece is before you move.

I need to take that same checking of validity in where you can move, and apply it in a separate method that will loop through the 2d array of JPanels that is my board and color the valid moves. The method would be called where "paintPossible(tempX, tempY)" is, and in the same spot in the "if" below.

Comment: I might use a `for-loop` which check every square to see if it was legal...

Comment: I apologize haha, I had a method earlier but deleted it because it didn't work, basically had two for loops, looping J from 0 to 10 inside of I, which was also looping from 0 to 10, and was calling getX() and getY() of each panel and checking for it to be within slightly less than one tile's worth of pixels of a legal tile, then if it was coloring it. For some reason that didn't work. I'm adding it to the code above^

Comment: I would virtualise your model, so that you can reference each cell simply (ie 1x1), then write a simple method that took the source cell and the target cell and return true/false if the piece at the start cell could move to the target cell.

Comment: Explain what virtualising is to me? I've never heard of that, and this is literally the last step in my program. I really don't have time to remake it all.

Comment: Your chess board should be a virtual concept, that is, you could interrogate the board using simple methods and absolute positioning (ie, `getPieceAt(1, 2)` which would get the piece on the second row and third column (Java been 0 indexed and all)).  This way, you don't care how the board is visually represented, only that the model access is consistent

Comment: I can do similar, I just use the width of the frame/an increment that gives me the square, with an underlying boolean array that tells me if theres a piece. I don't have a problem getting the piece and where it is, just painting the right tiles around it

Comment: [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - You'll find it easier if you separate your data/model from the view.  The model shouldn't care how it's visualised, it should only care about managing the data and ensure a correct state for the data, then the view can visualise it in any way it likes.  This makes it easier to modify either without adversely affecting each other

Comment: Consider, making a 2-D Array, for example for each piece of a chess game. Assign one number to each piece, like 1 for all Pawns, 2 for Rooks, 3 for Knights and so on. And when you click on the view, simply get the `(X,Y)` (say by using `JPanel.setName("" + row + " " + column)`) co-ordinates of that block, and iterate over this 2-D Array to see, where exactly the focus is on, and where exactly one can move. What you be doing here, is actually implementing the logic on numeric values, instead of view itself and whatever result you will get, you simply pass it to the view class.